# primefaces rowEdit Event to update table only if the event is a success

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am calling a rowEdit event and I want to refresh the table only when the event performs the db update successfully. Below are my code.

XHTML

```
 <p:dataTable id="xobjTable" var="xobj" value="#{xListView.xListResponseObject}"
                                 scrollRows="20" scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="600"
                                 rowKey="#{xobj.X}"
                                 selection="#{xListView.selectedObject}" selectionMode="single" 
                                 style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom:20px" editable="true">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Search Results
                            <p:spacer width="20"/>
                            <h:commandLink id="csv">
                                <p:graphicImage value="csv.png" width="24"/>
                                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="xobj" fileName="xListSearch" />
                                <p:tooltip id="toolTipFade" for="csv" value="Click on CSV to download entire table as a csv file. " />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{xListView.onRowEdit}" update=":xListform:xobjTable" />
                        <p:column headerText="X" style="width:60px;text-align: center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{xobj.X}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Y" style="width:60px;text-align: center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{xobj.Y}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Modified Date" style="width:160px;text-align: center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{xobj.modifiedDate}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Active" style="width:160px;text-align: center">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{xobj.active}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{xobj.active}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{xListView.activeList}" />
                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Location" style="width:160px;text-align: center">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{xobj.location}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputText id="location" value="#{xobj.location}" />  
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="State" style="width:160px;text-align: center">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{xobj.state}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputText id="state" value="#{xobj.state}" />  
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="x Country Code" style="width:160px;text-align: center">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{xobj.xCountryCode}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputText id="xCountryCode" value="#{xobj.xCountryCode}" />  
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="xrarier" style="width:160px;text-align: center">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{xobj.carrier}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{xobj.carrier}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{xListView.xarrierList}" />
                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Edit" rendered="#{allTabs.isShow(xListView.title)}">
                            <p:rowEditor />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:160px;text-align: center" rendered="#{allTabs.isShow(xListView.title)}" headerText="Delete">
                            <p:commandButton id="deleteDid"  actionListener="#{xListView.deletexy(xobj)}"  
                                             icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash red" title="Delete"  update="@form">
                                <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="#{xListView.finalDeleteMessage}"  icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

Here is the event method

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        xListResponseObject editObject = (xListResponseObject) event.getObject();
        logger.debug("Coming to edit the row.");
        String editXYStatus = xListDAO.editxy(editObject);
        if (editxyStatus.equals(SUCCESS_RESPONSE)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "INFO", "X/Y edit successful!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "INFO", "X/Y edit failed :" + editxyStatus);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }

    }
```

I would like the update to happen only when the rowEdit event updates the db.
Can I have a boolean set in my method and access data in the update in the p:ajax ?

Comment: Use the `RequestContext` in you bean and update the component from there only if your dbaction was successful

Answer (score 1):

Add to end of your SUCCESS_RESPONSE

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:npaobjTable");
```

Or whatever your table real id is.

Comment: I tried the above and remove the update from the p:ajax and addit to the rowEdit event but still the table gets updated with invalid record. Below are my changes.                                                                                                        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{npaListView.onRowEdit}" />

Comment: if (editNpaNxxStatus.equals(SUCCESS_RESPONSE)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "INFO", "NPA/NXX edit successful!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":npaListform:npaobjTable");
        }

Comment: You are not processing new values <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{npaListView.onRowEdit}" process=":npaListform:npaobjTable" />

Comment: Not working. Still its updating the cell with invalid values even if my DAO action fails.

Comment: Even if I dont use the RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update the cell updates itself if I click on the tick once I click on the edit pencil. So was wondering if we can control the cell update instead of it doing it automatically. Thanks

Comment: This is whole another problem, not about updating a dataTable, you will need to tell your whole story, what are you trying to achieve. And the code  you are trying it with. Open a new question.

Comment: Code is the same as above what is needed is on clicking the row edit it calls the actionListener for onRowEdit which can be a success or a failure. Incase it fails we dont need the row to get updated with the incorrect user entered values. But if the action is a success then update the row.

Comment: Can I get the old values and keep them and update the row in case my db action failed but I don't know how to do that any help would be great thanks

Comment: Like i said, i can't tell from above code how are you creating your datatable source(npaListView.npaListResponseObject)  i can only assume it is created from DB. I do not see how are you updating DB with npaListDAO.editNpaNxx(object). With update you will refresh your dataTable with whatever values are in your npaListResponseObject and with process"npaListform:npaobjTable" you will send values of that table component, but if you do not update DB or whatever is your npaListResponseObject, with that values the old ones will always get shown when update is executed.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem.
Below URL will solve your problem.

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38412&p=153402#p153402

actual response :

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        NpaListResponseObject editObject = (NpaListResponseObject) event.getObject();
        logger.debug("Coming to edit the row.");
        String editNpaNxxStatus = npaListDAO.editNpaNxx(editObject);
        if (editNpaNxxStatus.equals(SUCCESS_RESPONSE)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "INFO", "NPA/NXX edit successful!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "INFO", "NPA/NXX edit failed :" + editNpaNxxStatus);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
        }

    }
```

added FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed(); at last in failure scenario.

Comment: Please add an actual explanation and response here, not just a link to another response

Comment: edited the code as per your suggestion. added FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed(); at the last line.

Comment: Still, you should provide a real **explanation** on how to solve the problem, e.g. explain what the code does, where to add it, etc. An answer should be descriptive and not some copy-paste !

Comment: All the explanation is there in the question itself. There is no more explanation required.